# How do I change the designs of ascii codes in 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, character-encoding, x86-16, hebrew, tasm

Im trying to redefine how the characters will look (in this case according to the Hebrew alphabet). In this segment I wanted to change 'k' (ascii 6bh) to resemble this ל.

```
.model small
.stack 200h
```

;data segment containing all of the variables used in the program
.data
    Lamed db 30h, 30h, 30h, 3fh, 3h, 3h, 3h, 6h, 0ch, 18h, 30h
.code
    Start:
    mov ax, @data

`mov es, ax
mov ax, 1110h
mov bh, 14h
mov bl, 1h
mov cx, 1h
mov dx, 6bh
push bp
mov bp, offset Lamed
int 10h
pop bp

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 6bh
int 21h
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
end Start`

Also if there is a predefined hebrew alphabet that would help.

Comment: Google for "codepage". There's certainly one that has hebrew characters.

Comment: Turns out to be codepage 862.

Comment: Thank you for both your informative answers. I was wondering how I would go about changing the codepage to 862?

Comment: You might want to explore the many uses of the "MODE" command. Consult any good DOS manual.

Answer (score 2):

- Best not use the function 1110h (that also changes the height)! Better stick with function 1100h.
- Trough `mov bl, 1h` you've asked for font block 1. But mostly font block 0 is the active one. Better change this.
- You defined only 11 bytes of data at *Lamed*.  But you've instructed BIOS to retrieve 20 bytes by using `mov bh, 14h`. That clearly won't work.
  If this is standard 80x25 text video then use a value of 16 and pad the data with space represented by extra zeroes.

You could write:

```
Lamed db 0, 0, 0, 30h, 30h, 30h, 3fh, 3h, 3h, 3h, 6h, 0ch, 18h, 30h, 0, 0
```